# How did they toss the ladder to the other end?

Tags: plot-explanation, tomb-raider-2018

We see the end of the ladder is not fixed, as well 
as being held by the other end by them. Before that, 
I wonder, how did they toss the ladder to the other end?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, you'd hold the ladder vertically with one end on the ground near the edge, and then let it the other end drop forwards, bridging the gap (provided you've measured the distance and the length of the ladder effectively enough).  You kind of hope that the weight/length of the ladder doesn't conspire to snap/bend/weaken it from the downward momentum.

Or two people can hold the middle of the ladder between them and simply toss the ladder across the gap, tethering the near end so the whole lot doesn't disappear into the abyss.  There's only so far that you can toss a ladder though.

I seem to remember in the film that there probably wasn't enough headroom in the cavern to do the lift-and-drop technique.  So as with many films of this kind, it was placed there

> By the power of plot

Comment: If you have a long enough rope, you should be able to push the ladder across the gap, using the rope to stop the unsupported end from falling until it's in place on the other side. If the unsupported end does drop, you can anchor your end and pull on the rope, which should cause the other end of the ladder to lift. You could even let the end drop intentionally, which would be the opposite of your first suggestion, without requiring a lot of space **above** the gap you're trying to bridge. I don't think there's any indication ropes were involved in the movie, though.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist If the weight and leverage exerted by the end of the ladder doesn't pull the end of the ladder downward beyond the point of no return...

Comment: They have machinery, vehicles and a large population of prisoner slaves at their disposal, so I don't think that should ever be a problem. It may not work solo, or in a small group, but in the context of the movie, it should be feasible.

Comment: From what I recall of the 2018 film, in that cavern, there was Lara, her father, the primary bad guy and 5 or 6 goons.  I'm guessing it might have been possible for the bad guy to call out for additional men & machinery to come int, get the ladder across, and then immediately dismiss them again.